# All font variations present, but @font-face still wont work in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, fonts, font-face

I am using `@font-face` on my site.

One call I have is simply:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: bebas;
    src: url('bebas.TTF');
}
```

And that seems to work fine in IE 9/10.

However, I have tried making this work with another font:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: lobster;
    src: url('lobster.OTF');
}
```

And had no success in IE.

I've Googled answers and many suggest using the [Font Squirrel Font Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to get the complete code, which I did here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lobster';
    src: url('lobster-webfont.eot');
    src: url('lobster-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lobster-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lobster-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lobster-webfont.svg#lobster_1.4regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

but still the font will not display correctly.

I have included all the additional files within the right directory - it just wont work in IE.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Tried converting the font to TTF - no luck there either

EDIT2: Example of CSS used:

```
#tickerlist LI
{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: lobster, Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40.3pt;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

EDIT3:

Tried absolute paths to font files - still no affect

Comment: To begin with, where did you get the font from, and what exact code (including both HTML and CSS) did you use? The problem cannot be reconstructed from the data provided.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I got the font from Font Squirrel. I have added the CSS where I call the font above

Comment: Could it be that you need to add the MIME Type to your server for the IE font?

Comment: You've got an uppercase LI in the CSS. The page is not an XHTML document, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following

- Check that your path to the font on your web server is correct. I tend to store fonts in /fonts/ in my apps / sites
- Since you got this from fontsquirrel download the font package and test it locally in IE 9 to make sure it works.
- Check to make sure your don't have any definitions open in your css file, missing a semi-colon: can sometimes mess you up.
- Check to make sure your server is serving up the right mime-type for .eot files
- I also make sure I have the appropriate quotes or ticks around the font you are trying to serve up.

  p.mine {font-family: 'lobster', Arial, sans-serif;}